# Surjectivity/Commutativity of Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm learning about Lie groups, and I was recently able "prove" a false result and am not sure where my reasoning went wrong. I was able to show that a connected finite-dimensional Lie group is abelian, which can't be true. My main reference is "Intro to Smooth Manifolds" by Lee, and here's my chain of reasoning:

1. **There exists a global commuting frame on G**: If $(U_e,\phi)$ is a smooth chart where $U_e$ is a neighborhood of the identity element $e$, we can let $V_1, \cdots, V_n$ be the left-invariant vector fields generated by the coordinates derivatives wrt to the chart at $T_e G$. These form a commuting frame, and every $g \in G$ has the chart $(L_g(U_e), \phi \circ L_{g^{-1}})$ such that $V_i$ corresponds to the $i^{th}$ coordinate derivative in chart coordinates. Here $L_g$ refers to left translation by $g$, which is a diffeomorphism.
2. **Every element of $G$ can be reached by following flows of the frame $V_1, \cdots, V_n$**: $G$ is connected and therefore path connected, so there exists a path $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow G$ from $e$ to $g$ for any $g \in G$. Cover the path $\gamma$ with the open sets $L_{\gamma(t)} U_e$ and get a finite subcover since $\gamma([0,1])$ is compact. Choose points $p_1, \cdots, p_m$ at the intersection of these charts so that $p_1 \rightarrow p_2 \rightarrow \cdots p_m$ breaks up $\gamma$ into smaller paths and ($p_i, p_{i+1}$) lie within a single open set. Passing to the coordinate chart $(L_g U_e, \phi \circ L_{g^{-1}})$, we can get from $\phi(p_i)$ to $\phi(p_{i+1})$ by moving along the first coordinate, then the second, etc. This amounts to following the flows of the coordinate derivatives, and hence by 1 mapping back to $G$ this means following the flows of $V_i$. Composing these paths together makes a path from $e$ to $g$ following the flows of $V_i$. Since the flows commute, we can move terms around and group paths along the same flow together. If $\theta^i$ denotes the flow of $V_i$, then every element $g = \theta^1_{t_1} \circ \cdots \theta^n_{t_n}(e)$ for some $t_1, \cdots, t_n$.
3. **$G$ is abelian**: If $X, Y$ are commuting vector fields, then the flow of $X+Y$ is $\theta_X(t) \circ \theta_Y(t)$. If $X,Y \in Lie(G)$ and they commute, then $\exp(sX + tY) = \exp(sX)\exp(tY)$. Hence, $g = \theta^1_{t_1} \circ \cdots \theta^n_{t_n}(e) = \Pi \exp(t_i V_i)$, the product of commuting terms. Since every $g$ can be written as a product of these commuting terms, then $gh = hg$ is we decompose them as a product of commuting exponentials.

I'm not sure where I went wrong in my reasoning, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you claim the frame in 1. is commuting?

Comment: My reasoning is that at $T_e G$ with the chart $(U_e, \phi)$, the coordinate derivs commute so $\frac{d}{d x_i}\frac{d}{d x_j} - \frac{d}{d x_j}\frac{d}{d x_i} = 0$ in $T_e G$. Since $V_i$ is left-invariant and Lie brackets represent left-translation, $[V_i, V_j]_g = dL_g ([V_i, V_j]_e) = dL_g (0) = 0$, so $[V_i, V_j]$ is the zero vector field.

Comment: The error is in the assumption that $V_i|_e=\partial/\partial x^i|_e$ implies $[V_i,V_j]_e=[\partial/\partial x^i, \partial/\partial x^j]_e$.  This is not true in general as the Lie bracket is not tensorial.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. Thanks so much! For anyone else reading this, one example would be $V = (1+x_1) \partial / \partial x_1$ and $W = x_1 \partial / \partial x_1 + \partial / \partial x_2$. At (0,0) $V = \partial / \partial x_1$ and $W = \partial / \partial x_2$. However, their Lie bracket can be computed as: $[V, W] = (V W^j - W V^j) \partial / \partial x_j = \partial / \partial x_1 \neq 0$.